# MySQL How to link two column in "where.."

Tags: mysql

I'm a beginner in MySQL and I have some trouble to select specific data from one table.

Here's the table (School) :

```
ID  Year   Class
1   B1     PSC
2   B1     PRI
3   B1     SLG
4   B2     PSC
5   B2     PRI
6   B2     SLM
7   B3     PRI
8   B3     SLH
9   B3     SLG
10  B3     SLF
11  B3     PSC
```

I would like to select all the data except where Year='`B3`' and Class='`S%`' at the same time.

So the result would be :

```
ID  Year   Class
1   B1     PSC
2   B1     PRI
3   B1     SLG
4   B2     PSC
5   B2     PRI
6   B2     SLM
7   B3     PRI
11  B3     PSC
```

My current query is

```
"Select * from School where Class NOT LIKE ('S%') and Year!='B3'"
```

but I only get:

```
ID  Year   Class
1   B1     PSC
2   B1     PRI
4   B2     PSC
5   B2     PRI
```

What is the documentation for my situation?
Need to learn :)

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Use `or` instead of `and`.

Comment: @Phylogenesis You should put that as an answer with an explanation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your *statement* now says it should not be `like S%` and not `B3`. What your *text* is telling it should not be `like S%` **or** not `B3`.

So, change *and* to *or*:

```
select *
from   School
where  Class NOT LIKE ('S%')
or     Year!='B3'"
```

Comment: Finally, an answer that explains the fault. **+1**

Comment: This query doesn't work. If you look at the expected result set, it should include the record with id = 3. This query would not return that row.

Comment: @BrianGlaz It looks fine to me, the `Year != 'B3'` predicate would return `true` for that row.

Comment: @BrianGlaz  It shall return the correct answer. Downvote for me too :(

Comment: Formally, in [boolean algebra](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boolean_algebra_(structure)): `¬(A ^ B) = ¬A v ¬b`.

Comment: @Phylogenesis Yes Buddy. You are right. So using that formula query is correct. Right :)

`Not(A And B) = Not(A) OR  Not(B)`

There is one downvote for me too :(

Answer (score 1):

lets break this one down...

You have condition `A: Year='B3'` 
and condition `B: Class = '%S'`

Now you want to select all rows for which both conditions are wrong ==> `NOT (A and B)` 
Using [De Morgan's laws](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws) you can now transform this into `NOT A OR NOT B` which means for your specific case that your query needs to look like 
`SELECT * FROM School WHERE Class NOT LIKE ('S%') OR Year!='B3'`

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `OR` instead of `And`.

(As you want to exclude those records which have Class starting with 'S' and Year = B3.)

```
"Select * from School where Class NOT LIKE 'S%' OR Year!='B3'"
```

Answer (score 0):

Add a not infront of your restricting statement and change the `!=`  to a `=`

```
Select * from School where not (Class LIKE ('S%') and Year = 'B3')
```

you define the matching `Class LIKE ('S%') and Year = 'B3'` and with the `not` infront of it you tell the query to exclude these results.

I created a [sqlfiddle here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/46c55/3/0) to test it.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT x.* 
  FROM school x 
  LEFT 
  JOIN school y 
    ON y.id = x.id 
   AND y.year = 'B3' 
   AND y.class LIKE 'S%' 
 WHERE y.id IS NULL;
```

Comment: Code only answers are discouraged.  http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/148274/246338

Answer (score 0):

```
Select * from School where Class NOT LIKE 'S%' and Year = 'B3'
```

Comment: Code only answers are discouraged.  http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/148274/246338

Answer (score 0):

use or not and in where clause

Select * from School where Class NOT LIKE ('S%') **OR** Year!='B3'"